# How to assign a kind to a group of things

Tags: inform7

I'm new to Inform 7. I've been playing around with the 'Bogart' example which provides some rules for clothing.

I have something like:

```
The player wears a jacket, a jumper, a shirt, some underpants, a pair of men's blue jeans, a pair of socks.
```

Now I want to add a property to clothing, e.g.:

```
An item of clothing is a kind of thing.

An item of clothing can be removable. An item of clothing is usually removable.
```

At this point it looks like I have to go through and explicitly define each item worn by the player as being an `item of clothing`, such as:

```
A pair of socks is an item of clothing.  
A jumper is an item of clothing.  
A jacket is an item of clothing.
```

...etc for everything the player is wearing.

I would like to find a way to tell Inform that `everything worn by the player is an item of clothing` or even `everything wearable is an item of clothing`. So far I haven't found any form of this that will compile, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. The best you can do is:

```
The jacket, the jumper, the shirt, the underpants, the pair of men's blue jeans, 
and the pair of socks are item of clothing.
```